# Having trouble with onCellSelect setup in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am successfully retrieving data from my controller method and want to display data on the jqGrid.

I notice during debugging, that I get an error message that pops up (which I'm not expecting) that says "Element is not a table".

The error occurs on the line trying to set up the **onCellSelect** event for the grid. It appears that it's trying to read data in a grid that is not yet populated.

Notice that I am populating the grid after this event. This event is for after the grid is populated to pull a value out of a cell.

However, I thought that all events need to be set up on the definition of the grid at design time.

**Can someone please inform me what I'm doing wrong here?**

Here is my pertinent code:

```
$.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetFilteredFuelTicketsAsync")',
                            type: "POST",
                            data: JSON.stringify(HH_FuelTkt_Input),
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#fuelTickets').jqGrid({
                                    caption: "Fuel Tickets",
                                    colNames: ["ID", "Ticket", "Vehicle", "Customer", "Date", "Image ID"],
                                    colModel: [
                                                { name: "FuelTkt_ID", viewable: false },
                                                { name: "Ticket_No", width: 30, align: "right" },
                                                { name: "Vehicle_No", width: 50 },
                                                { name: "Customer_Name", width: 100 },
                                                { name: "Trans_Timestamp", width: 100, datefmt: "yyyy-mm-dd" },
                                                { name: "Image_ID", width: 30 }
                                    ],
                                    datatype: "json",
                                    mtype: "GET",
                                    pager: true,
                                    sortname: "Ticket_No",
                                    sortorder: "Asc",
                                    viewRecords: true,
                                    gridview: true,
                                    autoWidth: true,
                                    emptyRecords: "No records found",
                                    onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
                                        var grid = $('#fuelTickets');
                                        var imageID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Image_ID');
                                        if (imageID != "")
                                            DisplayReceipt(imageID);
                                    }
                                })
                                var grid = $("#fuelTickets");
                                var gridData = JSON.parse(data.d);
                                grid.clearGridData();
                                for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
                                    grid.addRowData(i + 1, gridData[i]);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("No record found: " + "textStatus: " + textStatus + "\r\n" + "errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                            }
                        });
```

EDIT AFTER PLACING JQGRID IN TABLE ELEMENT (which fixed the immediate problem):
It was because I didn't have the jqGrid defined in a table element...

However, another thing popped up here.

I get two records back in the variable "data".

When I try and process this line, nothing happens. The browser just hangs. Do I need to bind the data to the grid a different way? It's obvioulsy having problems parsing the data, maybe with the timestamp. Could you suggest what I might be able to do to resolve this?

Thanks so much.
var gridData = JSON.parse(data.d);

The json data looks like this:

data 
[Object { FuelTkt_ID=2, Ticket_No=6460193, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}, Object { FuelTkt_ID=3, Ticket_No=6460194, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}]

0 
Object { FuelTkt_ID=2, Ticket_No=6460193, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}

Customer_Name 
"X"

FuelTkt_ID 
2

Image_ID 
"12345"

Ticket_No 
6460193

Trans_Timestamp 
"/Date(1395238800000)/"

Vehicle_No 
"123456"

1 
Object { FuelTkt_ID=3, Ticket_No=6460194, Vehicle_No="123456", more...}

Customer_Name 
"X"

FuelTkt_ID 
3

Image_ID 
"22856"

Ticket_No 
6460194

Trans_Timestamp 
"/Date(1395246000000)/"

Vehicle_No 
"123456"

Comment: Is the above code being run after the jQuery onReady event?

Comment: Yes, it is... I really need help with this one... It's got to be a common mistake. Basically, how do you set up events on the grid at design time.

Comment: Even after I removed the "onCellSelect" event, I got the same exact error right after the "emptyRecords" property. This definitely tells me that there is something wrong in the format of the way I'm setting up the grid. I would appreciate anybody's input...

Comment: What do you get in the console if you run `$('#fuelTickets').length`?

Comment: I get one record back: $('#fuelTickets').length 1

Comment: Can you post the HTML involving the element with an id="fuelTickets"?

Comment: It's just a div where I want the grid to appear like so: <div id="fuelTickets">
            </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid requires the element you attach it to to be a table:

```
<table id="fuelTickets"> </table>
```

Comment: Yes, that was it... thanks. But I edited my post for another issue that came up with the data binding... If you could help out there, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: There's not much you can do about bad data but change the data. If you don't want the browser to hang, you could use a try/catch.